# passing props from parent to child react router TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-props

Im new to React and TS. I'm trying to pass an accesskey from parent to child in a react route.

When console.logging on parent, I have the key, but it doesnt seem I'm able to pass the key down to the child. I've been trying around for a couple of hours with no luck what so ever. Any advice/help?

Parent:

```
let token = ""

function ActiveLink({to, children, ...props} : any){
  const resultPath = useResolvedPath(to)
  const isActive = useMatch({path: resultPath.pathname, end:true})
  return(
    <li className={isActive? "active" : ""}>
      <Link to={to} {...props}>
        {children}
      </Link>
    </li>
  )
}

type AppProps = {
  pca: IPublicClientApplication
};


function ProfileContent() {
    const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState<any | null>(null);
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<any | null>("");
    
    
    
    var name = accounts[0] && accounts[0].name;
    var name = name?.split(',')[1];
    

   
    React.useEffect(() => {
      const request = {
          ...loginRequest,
          account: accounts[0]
      };

      // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for Microsoft Graph data
      instance.acquireTokenSilent(request).then((response) => {
        callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then(response => setGraphData(response));
        setAccessToken(response.accessToken) 
        token = response.accessToken;   
        

    }).catch((e) => {
        instance.acquireTokenPopup(request).then((response) => {
            callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then(response => setGraphData(response));
            
        });
    });
},[]);

return (
    <>
        <p className="card-title">Velkommen tilbake,</p>
        <h5 className="navBar-name">{name}</h5>
        <h5></h5>
        <Link to="/oversikt" className="test">Min oversikt</Link>
        <Link to="/oppdrag" className="test">Mine oppdrag</Link>
        <Link to="/ansvarsområde" className="test">Mitt ansvarsområde</Link>
        {graphData && accessToken? 
        <div>
            <ProfileData graphData={graphData}/>
            <ProfilePic accessToken={accessToken}/>
            
            </div>
            :
            
            <h5>Something bad happened, error!</h5>
        }
    </>
);
};


function App({ pca }: AppProps) {
  return (
  <div>
    <nav> 
    <MsalProvider instance={pca}>
    <Routes>
          <Route path = "/oversikt" element={<Oversikt/>}/>
          <Route path = "/oppdrag/*" element={<Mineoppdrag/>}/>
          <Route path = "/oppdrag/rapport"element= {<PowerBIClient accessToken={token}/>}/>
          <Route path = "/ansvarsområde" element={<Ansvarsområde/>}/>
          <Route path = "/login" element={<UnauthenticatedTemplate/>}/>
        </Routes>
        <PageLayout>
          <AuthenticatedTemplate>
          <div id ="container">
          <ProfileContent/>
          </div>
          </AuthenticatedTemplate>
          <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
            <div className="signinText">You are not signed in. Please sign in!</div>
          </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        </PageLayout> 
        </MsalProvider> 
        </nav>  
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child:

```
interface myProps {
    accessToken: string,
}


declare global {
    interface Window {
        report:any;
    }
}





export default class PowerBIClient extends React.Component<myProps> {
    public render() {
    console.log(this.props.accessToken + "TOKEN")
    
   return (
    <PowerBIEmbed
    embedConfig = {
        {
            type: 'report', // Supported types: report, dashboard, tile, visual, and qna.
            embedUrl: "url",
            accessToken: this.props.accessToken,
            tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,  for your organization.
            settings: {
                panes: {
                    filters: {
                        expanded: false,
                        visible: true
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    eventHandlers = {
        new Map([ 
            ['loaded', function () {
                console.log('Report loaded');
            }],
            ['rendered', function () {
                console.log('Report rendered');
            }],
            ['error', function (event:any) {
                console.log(event.detail);
            }]
        ] )
    }
    
    cssClassName = {
        "Embed-container"
    }
    
    getEmbeddedComponent = {
        (embeddedReport) => {
            window.report = embeddedReport;
            console.log(this.props.accessToken + "TOKEN")
        }
    }
/>

   )
   
}

}
```

UPDATE:

```
function ActiveLink({to, children, ...props} : any){
  const resultPath = useResolvedPath(to)
  const isActive = useMatch({path: resultPath.pathname, end:true})
  return(
    <li className={isActive? "active" : ""}>
      <Link to={to} {...props}>
        {children}
      </Link>
    </li>
  )
}

type AppProps = {
  pca: IPublicClientApplication
  
};


function ProfileContent({accessToken, setAccessToken}:any) {
    const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState<any | null>(null);
    //const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<any | null>("");
    

  

    
    var name = accounts[0] && accounts[0].name;
    var name = name?.split(',')[1];
    

  
   
    React.useEffect(() => {
      const request = {
          ...loginRequest,
          account: accounts[0]
      };


      // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for Microsoft Graph data
        
        instance.acquireTokenSilent(request).then((response) => {
        callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then(response => setGraphData(response)).catch((e) =>{
          console.log(e)
        }
        
        )
        if(response.accessToken)
        setAccessToken(response.accessToken)
        
        console.log(accessToken + "TOKEN")
          
        

    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e , "TokenPopUPError")
        instance.acquireTokenPopup(request).
        then((response) => {
            callMsGraph(response.accessToken)
            .then(response => setGraphData(response));
            setAccessToken(response.accessToken)
        });
    });
},[]);


return (
    <>
      
        <p className="card-title">Velkommen tilbake,</p>
        <h5 className="navBar-name">{name}</h5>
        <h5></h5>
        <Link to="/oversikt" className="test">Min oversikt</Link>
        <Link to="/oppdrag" className="test">Mine oppdrag</Link>
        <Link to="/ansvarsområde" className="test">Mitt ansvarsområde</Link>
        {graphData && accessToken? 
        <div>
            <ProfileData graphData={graphData}/>
            <ProfilePic accessToken={accessToken}/>
            
            </div>
            :
            
            <h5>Something bad happened, error!</h5>
        }
    </>
);
};


function App({ pca }: AppProps) {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<string>();

  return (
  <div>
    <nav> 
    <MsalProvider instance={pca}>
 
    <Routes>
          <Route path = "/oversikt" element={<Oversikt/>}/>
          <Route path = "/oppdrag/*" element={<Mineoppdrag/>}/>
          <Route path = "/oppdrag/rapport"element= {<PowerBIClient accessToken={accessToken}/>}/>
          <Route path = "/ansvarsområde" element={<Ansvarsområde/>}/>
          <Route path = "/login" element={<UnauthenticatedTemplate/>}/>
        </Routes>
        <PageLayout>
          <AuthenticatedTemplate>
          <div id ="container">
          <ProfileContent accessToken={accessToken}/>
          </div>
          </AuthenticatedTemplate>
          <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
            <div className="signinText">You are not signed in. Please sign in!</div>
          </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        </PageLayout> 
        </MsalProvider> 
        </nav>  
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: where is that `token` prop declared in `App`

Comment: @FerToasted I've updated the post. Its inn the parent. Thanks!

Comment: `token` is undeclared in the `App` component. What exactly is the parent-child relationship you are referring to? `PowerBIClient` is rendered by a `Route` component rendered in `App`. If `ProfileContent` is the component with the `accessToken` state that you want passed to `PowerBlClient` then you will want/need to [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common ancestor component, like `App`, and pass what you need down as props or Context or global app state etc. Do you need help with this part?

Comment: Oh, I see now... you've declared an unrestricted global `let token = ""` in the code you've labeled "parent" and are mutating it. Don't do this. Updates to this value won't trigger anything in React to work like you probably want it to since it's completely outside the scope of React.

Comment: On further investigation. It seems like my variable "token" (at the top of the parent) gets empty after I set its new value

Comment: Yeah, it doesnt. What would you suggest me to do with as little as re-work as possible? @Drew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `accessToken` state up to the common ancestor, the `App` component and pass it and the state updater function down to the descendent components that need to access it.

See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) for more details.

Example:

```
function App({ pca }: AppProps) {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<string>(""); // <-- declare state

  return (
    <div>
      <nav> 
        <MsalProvider instance={pca}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/oversikt" element={<Oversikt />} />
            <Route path="/oppdrag/*" element={<Mineoppdrag />} />
            <Route
              path="/oppdrag/rapport"
              element= {<PowerBIClient accessToken={accessToken} />} // <-- pass down as props
            />
            <Route path="/ansvarsområde" element={<Ansvarsområde />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<UnauthenticatedTemplate />} />
          </Routes>
          <PageLayout>
            <AuthenticatedTemplate>
              <div id ="container">
                <ProfileContent {...{ accessToken, setAccessToken }}/> // <-- pass down as props
              </div>
            </AuthenticatedTemplate>
            <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
              <div className="signinText">
                You are not signed in. Please sign in!
              </div>
            </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
          </PageLayout> 
        </MsalProvider> 
      </nav>  
    </div>
  );
}
```

...

```
function ProfileContent({ accessToken, setAccessToken }) {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState<any | null>(null);
    
  var name = accounts[0] && accounts[0].name;
  var name = name?.split(',')[1];
   
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const request = {
      ...loginRequest,
      account: accounts[0]
    };

    // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for Microsoft Graph data
    instance.acquireTokenSilent(request)
      .then((response) => {
        callMsGraph(response.accessToken)
          .then(response => setGraphData(response));
        setAccessToken(response.accessToken);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        instance.acquireTokenPopup(request)
          .then((response) => {
            callMsGraph(response.accessToken)
              .then(response => setGraphData(response));
          });
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <p className="card-title">Velkommen tilbake,</p>
      <h5 className="navBar-name">{name}</h5>
      <h5></h5>
      <Link to="/oversikt" className="test">Min oversikt</Link>
      <Link to="/oppdrag" className="test">Mine oppdrag</Link>
      <Link to="/ansvarsområde" className="test">Mitt ansvarsområde</Link>
      {graphData && accessToken
      ? ( 
        <div>
          <ProfileData graphData={graphData}/>
          <ProfilePic accessToken={accessToken}/>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <h5>Something bad happened, error!</h5>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: @AlexanderBrandhaug `setAccessToken` is passed as a prop to `ProfileContent` so it can pass the fetched token value back out to the parent component, `App`, holding the state. *Then* the parent component passes the `accessToken` state down as props to components that need it, like the `PowerBIClient` component.

Comment: @AlexanderBrandhaug I noticed your comment was removed between me starting to respond and adding my comment. Does this make sense now?

Comment: Thanks again - I gotcha. However - I ran into a different issue upon updating my code to your suggestion which Im struggling with, I therefor can't verify if your solution works.. 

Im getting the error: 

Uncaught (in promise) BrowserAuthError: interaction_in_progress: Interaction is currently in progress. Please ensure that this interaction has been completed before calling an interactive API.  For more visit: aka.ms/msaljs/browser-errors.

Comment: @AlexanderBrandhaug Well, at least in `ProfileContent` you've several Promise chains going and ***none*** of them have a `.catch` block to handle any Promise rejections and other thrown errors. Could that be part of this other issue? You could at least flatten the nested Promises out to the main Promise chain and add a single `.catch` for each chain for these cases.

Comment: I've added a couple of catches, and I managed to get this error console.logged:

TypeError: setAccessToken is not a function
    at App.tsx:66:

I assume thats because I'm using setAccessToken(response.accessToken)

I changed it to setAccessToken = response.accessToken

Comment: @AlexanderBrandhaug Interesting. If you managed to implement things correctly I'd fully expect `setAccessToken` to be the state updater function returned from the `useState` hook. Can you double check the state declaration and how it's passed down as props? You don't want to reassign it with `setAccessToken = response.accessToken` though.

Comment: I've updated my post with the entire current code for app.tsx - greatly appreciate your time and help!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248094/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-alexander-brandhaug).